# Onenote API and Onenote Interop

Tags: onenote

Gday.

I am familiar with writing code to access/edit a notebook stored at a directory using the Onenote Interop classes for Desktop versions of OneNote (2007, 2010, 2013)

Now that the OnenoteAPI is out for the cloud-based OneNote (Win RT OneNote, WinPhone OneNote, and etc) I am confused as to which to use.

I'm trying to build an app that uses Onenote to store some notes. The notes will generally be accessed from few locations in a city and perhaps some mobile computers. With the Interop method, I already have a solution for (literally) copying some notebooks onto the mobile computers before they go out, and upon their return merging them back.

However, I would like to use "the cloud" as a storage option rather than storing the notebooks in one central location typically accessed through a jungle of VPNs. This is because some customers would be happy with the cloud (and not having their own server) and others will be want to at least have a copy of the data, and use the cloud as a means to be more mobile.

Now, I haven't gone around implementing nor trying things out yet. I am seeking advice from people that may have done something similar. In particular, i'd like advice/hints/clues on how to:

1. Extract the notebook page content in a format from the OnenoteAPI that is compatible with the Interop. Similarly, push it back up to the OnenoteAPI from the Interop. Alternatively, can I somehow "export" a copy of the cloud Notebook and import it later?
2. Would expensive SharePoint help in some way? How about the free build-into-small-office-server version suffice?

Thank you Internets.

Comment: Does SharePoint even work with the free OneNote?

Comment: I've done some tests but I haven't finished yet. WinRT Onenote does not open locally stored Notebooks. WinRT Onenote can be tricked into trying to open a locally stored notebook using a URL- it then complains and says it only opens Sharepoint, Sharepoint 365 and Onedrive notebooks. Onedrive (on its local disk copy) does not show the Onenote notebook, only a link to it (somewhere i found that it was because onenote sync is different to onedrive sync and it would conflict if onedrive synced a notebook). Im now trying to see if i can deploy sharepoint and make that backup on onedrive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N.b. given the potential for confusion I will refer to the Win32-only OneNote API as "OneNote COM API" and the modern, web-based, and OneDrive-only REST API as the "OneNote REST API"

On #1: The HTML version of the OneNote pages we expose via the OneNote REST API does not have a 1:1 mapping to the OneNote Object Model that is exposed via the COM API; this makes interop between them difficult. Furthermore, neither of them are designed to support a full-fidelity sync experience – it's a tricky problem, and usually one where people are more than happy with the experience OneNote provides out-of-the-box.

On #2: SharePoint *could* solve your problem. When your users are in the office, OneNote would sync all of its changes to SharePoint and receive the deltas it missed while it was disconnected from the intranet. If clients desire mobility, you could open up SharePoint to web access. You can then build your app using the COM API against the desktop OneNote client and rely on OneNote itself to handle syncing.

The one caveat here is that not all SKUs of OneNote support accessing SharePoint notebooks; Win32 clients purchased as part of the Office suite can, as can any copy attached to an Office365 subscription, including Mac, iOS, and Android. To the best of my knowledge, Windows Phone does not have any such restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick. I may give Sharepoint a go. A question though, on the non-desktop onenote (so, wp, 'modern' onenote, android, ios) that has a sharepoint onenote open, how would an app interact with the onenote? I suppose I can't use COM on a non-desktop app, and I can't use REST because it's not a onedrive notebook. So, aside from opening a notebook using a URI ... there's nothing I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Update for Peter. the OneNote cloud APIs now support Sharepoint Online as a storage endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the headsup. I had seen the MS email from their connect site that said so. For now, my onenote usage is on hold anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but if someone is reading it I can add this:
OneNote + OneDrive does an EXCELLENT job of synchronizing a notebook that is opened on multiple devices, including PCs and phones.

My recommended solution for @Peter pete is to migrate his old COM OneNote to OneDrive.